# How to show left div below right div?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get this so that the div on the right is displayed above the div on the left when viewed at 900px or less.

Here is a link to the JS Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/lawrencetimmins/ycxkjya1/

Please help me fix this thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the order in HTML, so that the right DIV comes before the left on.

```
<div id="portfolio-right-1"></div>
<div id="portfolio-left-1"></div>
```

And set float right and left:

```
#portfolio-right-1
{
   float: right;
}

#portfolio-left-1
{ 
  float: left;
}
```

Now, when screen size is smaller then 900px and both divs are streched to 100% the "right" one comes first.

Comment: Thanks for that, not sure why i didn't think of that to be honest

Answer (score 0):

First Swap the divs around putting the one on the right first.

```
<div id="portfolio-right-1" class="right-column-portfolio-1"></div>
<div id="portfolio-left-1" class="left-column-portfolio-1"></div>
```

Next use a media selector in CSS to remove the float. Something like this

```
@media all and (max-width: 900px) {
    .left-column-portfolio-1, .right-column-portfolio-1 { 
        float: none;
        display: block; 
    }
}
```